# JSON to javascript to edit the value of JSON

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have a JSON file (.json).

```
"spinOptionArray" : [
 {"probability":100, "type": "string", "value": "SECTION 1", "resultText": "Please choose an item from Section 1"},
 {"probability":100, "type": "string", "value": "SECTION 2", "resultText": "Please choose an item from Section 2"},
 {"probability":100, "type": "string", "value": "SECTION 3", "resultText": "Please choose an item from Section 3"},
 {"probability":100, "type": "string", "value": "SECTION 4", "resultText": "Please choose an item from Section 4"},
 {"probability":100, "type": "string", "value": "SECTION 5", "resultText": "Please choose an item from Section 5"}, 
 {"probability":100, "type": "string", "value": "SECTION 6", "resultText": "Please choose an item from Section 6"}
]
```

How to I store the JSON file as a JS object instead? As I want to change the probability value in the JSON file with every click of the button.

Button html (in a .php file):

```
<button class="spinBtn" id="spinBtn">SPIN</button>
```

anyway, used this function to call the JSON

```
function loadJSON(callback) {
   var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
            xobj.open('GET', './wheel_data.json', true);
        xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                //Call the anonymous function (callback) passing in the response
                callback(xobj.responseText);
            }
        };
        xobj.send(null);
    }
```

Comment: `JSON.parse()` and/or `JSON.strinfigy()` ?

Comment: _As I want to change the probability value in the JSON file with every click of the button._ You mean you want to change the property and write it back to file ? you need some server side code for it

Comment: You will have to parse the JSON file, make the modifications on the resulting JS object in-memory, then rewrite the JSON file.

Comment: hi all, have added in how i call my json from the start.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey yes, that is what i want. what do you mean by server side code.

Comment: @RemLampa can you guide me through? cause i'm confused now

Answer (score 0):

If I were you then I'll use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for this kind of task. With localStorage you can easily

1. Store the string version of object using `localStorage.setItem()` and `JSON.stringify()`
2. To get data back on string use `localStorage.getItem()`, parse it to object using `JSON.parse()`
3. Do some modification as you wish e.g increment **probability** value in your case.
4. Again store that **modified** object data to string format with `localStorage.setItem()` and `JSON.stringify()`

TO store object data in string format with [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
localStorage.setItem('key_name',JSON.stringify(object));
```

TO get string data and make object [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key_name'));
```

```js
var before_btn_click =  [
 {"probability":100, "type": "string", "value": "SECTION 1", "resultText": "Please choose an item from Section 1"},
 {"probability":100, "type": "string", "value": "SECTION 2", "resultText": "Please choose an item from Section 2"},
 {"probability":100, "type": "string", "value": "SECTION 3", "resultText": "Please choose an item from Section 3"},
 {"probability":100, "type": "string", "value": "SECTION 4", "resultText": "Please choose an item from Section 4"},
 {"probability":100, "type": "string", "value": "SECTION 5", "resultText": "Please choose an item from Section 5"}, 
 {"probability":100, "type": "string", "value": "SECTION 6", "resultText": "Please choose an item from Section 6"}
];

//set the initial value on localStorage
if (localStorage.getItem('spinOptionArray') === null) {
  localStorage.setItem('spinOptionArray', JSON.stringify(before_btn_click));
}

document.getElementById('spinBtn').addEventListener('click',
  function() {

    spinOptionArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('spinOptionArray'));
    result = spinOptionArray.map(function(arrayItem) {
      return {
        probability: arrayItem['probability'] += 1,
        type: arrayItem['type'],
        value: arrayItem['value'],
        resultText: arrayItem['resultText']
      };
    })
    localStorage.setItem('spinOptionArray', JSON.stringify(result));
  })
```

```html
<button class="spinBtn" id="spinBtn">SPIN</button>
```

**SEE WORKING DEMO HERE** : https://jsfiddle.net/pez256hh/

To see the effect of Local Storage, just open your browser dev tools by **F12**

for Firefox: **Storage->Local Storage**

for Google Chrome : **Application -> Storage -> Local Storage**

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. however, is it possible to change the probability only for example, only value of SECTION 1 in the array instead of now, it changes all?

Comment: @being_sunny your code is good. i can see the local storage file is being changed for the probability. however, the web is not using the local storage changed json. it is still using the json file which i had initially. what did i miss out here?

Comment: @mistycloud If you don't have chance to use LocalStorage then, try the same logic with a .json file but use JSON.stringify() to store data to it, JSON.parse() to make it object , modify it as you wish and then finally store again on string format with JSON.stringify(). Hope I made you understand